# Visual Studio Database without SQL Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to make a Windows Form win32 application in Visual Studio 2010, but I know nothing about SQL. Can I create a database without a SQL Server? The information I will be storing will need to be filtered and calculated later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL CE Database instead of SQL Server. You can get more information about the difference between SQLCe and Sql Server Express

1. http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/sql-server-%E2%80%93-difference-between-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-and-sql-server-express-edition/
2. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/22/sql-server-difference-between-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-and-sql-server-express-edition/

Answer (score 0):

> Can I create a database without a SQL server?

Sure, you can MySQL, SQLite or any other provider that operates well with ADO.Net. Why don't you want to use a SQL Server though? Any particular reason?

There's also SQL Server Express that has a 10GB database limit, which is more than enough for a small application. Plus, it's 100% free.